# Creating a table with buttons in Android, compatible with both tablet and smartphone

Tags: android, xml, button

Hi Guys I'd like to create a menu page with buttons like in the picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Bx7.jpg
I already tried with linear layouts and table layouts, but it wasn't working. Can anyone help me? The buttons should be relative in size so the page is shown correctly on tablets and on smartphones.

Edit: This is my code

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did it in my app.. you can reference it. it does what you showed in the image.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#0099CC"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="#0099CC"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="#0099CC"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="#0099CC"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```